# Disposed button still disposed after postback when in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a table with buttons. The problem it has is when you click one button a new table gets drawn. When the new table is drawn the button is still clickable and if you press it again the page will give an error about the content holder having the same id. The whole table is in an update panel, I thought the update panel will release everything in it after a postback. But unfortunately it doesn't. (The table gets re drawn on every postback)

The idea I had now is disposing the button that was clicked, this way the burron can't be clicked twice. But if I click a button now and I click another one in another row the fisrt button is still disposed...

Do you know another way to do this or force the updatepanel to clear all teh buttons?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getFilterValues();
            getItemsOutOfviewState();
            drawTableOne();
        }
private void drawTableTwoClick(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton test = (ImageButton)(sender);
            test.ImageUrl = "~/img/minus.gif";
            test.Dispose();
            drawTableTwo(siteAlias, rowNumber);
        }

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up_tableMain" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tbl_main" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2" GridLines="Both" BackColor="White" class="tablesorter">
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a problem of viewstate because when you dispose the button it looses its reference in server side, although you can do the workaround with making 
`Button.Visible=false;`

and then under visible true condition do specific task or you can make button visible again at specific event. The Same is possible by making it disabled in server side code(c#) and checking it for redundancy.

Regards